# NGINX-RTMP Load Test

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I use Roman Arutyunyan's [NGINX-RTMP](http://nginx-rtmp.blogspot.com/) module with RTMP as input and HLS as the output. How can I load test it?

I want to know how much load the server can handle both from simultaneous streaming and viewing.

I found a tools called [Flazr](http://flazr.com/) that can test it, but it seems that it can only test RTMP view. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks Jay, I used the mobile app to ask in a hurry. Sorry for bad formatting

Comment: curious if there is a way to test this as well!